# Bus of 2d array in the verilog

Tags: verilog

After declaring the following:

```
reg [15:0] a [3:0][2:0]
```

I would like to get the value at index `[12] a [2][1]`,
how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a[2][1][12]
```

An N-dimensional array in Verilog is numbered like this:

```
reg [15:0] a [3:0][2:0]  ... [12345:0];
    (N+1)th   1st  2nd  ...     Nth
```

With a Verilog array you must index either *all* or *none* of the right-hand dimensions. Indexing the left-hand dimension is optional, but you can only do it if you've indexed the right-hand dimensions. So, you can

- refer to an array in its entirety: eg `a`
- refer to a single element of the array: eg `a[2][1]`
- refer to a bit or bits of a single element of an array: eg `a[2][1][12]`

Therefore, it makes sense to index the left-hand dimension last.